# Mysql get values missing in the In Clause

Tags: mysql

I want to get values missing in the in clause of a query

people

```
ID    |  Name | location_id | 
1     |    Rex|          5  |
2     |    Tex|          7  |
3     |    Jim|          8  |
4     |   John|          11 |
5     |    Tom|          12 |
```

Place

```
location_id | Place    |
5           | New York |
6           | London   |
7           | Madrid   |
8           | Paris    |   
9           | Dublin   |   
10          | Chicago  |   
11          | Berlin   |   
12          | Colombo  |
```

i want to find places where there are no people , when i give a list of locations in the in clause of the Query

i don't want to find all the locations which are not in the people table, only those ,in which i provide in the in clause

**Query**

```
SELECT location_id FROM people WHERE location_id in (5,6,7,8,9);
```

OUTPUT expected

```
|Location_id|
           6|
           9|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `JOIN` instead of two `IN` operations (improved performance).

Try this:

```
SELECT pl.location_id
FROM place pl LEFT JOIN
     people pp ON pl.location_id=pp.location_id
WHERE pp.location_id IS NULL 
      AND pl.location_id IN (5,6,7,8,9);
```

Result:

```
LOCATION_ID
6
9
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58bc1/5).

**EDIT:**

Without using `JOIN`:

```
SELECT location_id
FROM place
WHERE location_id NOT IN 
          (SELECT location_id FROM people)
AND pl.location_id IN (5,6,7,8,9);
```

Comment: The select distinct location_id from people, is that neccesary , as it does full table scan

Comment: @NaveenKumar: Updated my answer since a `join` is better than two `IN`s.

Comment: Can we do it with without joining with the place table

Comment: @NaveenKumar: Ofcourse, by using two `IN` operations. But I won't recommend that, since using `JOIN` is much faster than that.

Comment: @NaveenKumar: See the edit in my answer.

Comment: How do you do this on the same table?

Comment: @arjun, can you provide more information? have you asked a question on SO?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT location_id FROM place WHERE location_id NOT IN (SELECT location_id  FROM people) AND location_id IN (5,6,7,8,9);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Query

```
    select place from place 
          inner join poeple on place.location_id <> people.location_id where AND 
    place.location_id IN (5,6,7,8,9);
```

`Inner join` is use to join two or more table .

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.location_id FROM people p join Place l on 
p.location_id!=l.location_id WHERE p.location_id in (5,6,7,8,9);
```

Answer (score 0):

select l.location_id from people p left join place l on p.location_id=l.location_id where p.location_id not in (5,6,7,8,9)